# Finding slow parts of PHP code

Tags: php

I am new on php . i am currently on the project that have a php file contain approx 2500 line of code.

This script is working fine in localhost but on the server it take a lot of time to reload the page.

I want to know that is there any tool or website that find out the slow running code from php script.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Search for [php+profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+profiling).

Comment: Even though I added answer, but still -1 for not googling any info before asking.  There are tons of info about it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) for that - it has an integrated profiling solution. You can then parse these files with [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)

If you use software like XAMPP or MAMP, xdebug could be already with it. There are also lots of useful information how to setup xdebug like here http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/01/26/getting-xdebug-to-work-with-apachexampp-to-debug-php/

Maybe the server is also slower than your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) is pretty much the standard when it comes to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Some profiler will help here. The best of known to me is Xdebug. It has plugins for many IDEs.